# C Struct & Strcpy, dot operator does it resolve into a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

suppose i have something like this

```
typedef char string[21]    

struct planet_s
{
    string name,orbits;
    float distance;
    string discoverer;
    int yeardiscovered;
}one_planet;
```

next i need to initialize some information about the planet therefore my text book says

```
strcpy(one_planet.name, "Earth");         ?confused with these
strcpy(one_planet.orbits, "Sun");         ?
one_planet.distance = 150;
one_planet.mass = 6.00e+24;
strcpy(one_planet.discoverer, "me");     ?
one_planet.yeardiscovered = 1000;
```

my Confusion arises in the `strcpy`,let me put things in point form

`Strcpy` needs a pointer to a string as its first argument

does `one_planet.name` resolve into a pointer to the strcuts name array(does the dot operator resolve into an address)?

how come `one_planet.distance =150` does not resolve into an address since we are assign it its value straight away? this is what i been taught, one_planet.distance directly access the struct element and assigns it. my confusion is with the strcpy, since it needs an address to store a string?

hope you understand where my confusion comes form thanks.

Comment: @Adriano No, there's a very C-ish `typedef` that aliases a character array to the name `string`.

Comment: @unwind completely missed that!

Comment: @Adriano There is a `typedef` which probably should look like `typedef char[21] string` or `typedef char* string`. You are jumping to conclusions with `std::string` and `c++`. But the code as it is ... yeah it is far from ... even working.

Comment: @luk32: Actually, `typedef char string[21]` is correct. Welcome to C!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh, I turned out to be the prodigal son of `C`. I wandered of to land of `std::`s before I got to `typedef`ing constant sized vectors. Thanks for correction, every day something new to learn.

Comment: Invalid typedef, no closing quotes on string values, no semicolons in struct declaration between fields and no semicolon after struct declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, or when it is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

In the line

```
strcpy(one_planet.name, "Earth");
```

the expression `one_planet.name` has type "21-element array of `char`"; since the expression is not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted to an expression of type "pointer to `char`", and the address of the first element of the array is passed to `strcpy`.

The `.` operator doesn't make a difference in this case; what matters is the type of the *member*, regardless of how that member is accessed.

Answer (score 3):

The dot operator has nothing to do with this.

Compare your code to this:

```
int main(void)
{
  char string[21];

  strcpy(string, "Earth");

  return 0;
}
```

the above is 100% natural and fine C code, and it relies on the fact that in some contexts, the name of an array (`string`) evaluates to just a pointer to the first argument.

In other words, `string` above is evaluated to the exact same address value as the expression `&string[0]`.

The fact that your string is embedded inside a struct has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I think OP has serious troubles understanding `c` syntax at all, and you changed the meaning of `string` quite much. It can end up being highly confusing now. Especially when you encourage to compare the codes. Maybe leaving `typedef` would be more useful... Although I am not good at teaching programming. Just an idea.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not the "dot operator" `.` that creates a pointer, it's because e.g. the `orbits` member is an array. All arrays decays to pointers when passed as arguments.